# Spinner in ActionBar doesn't appear

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-spinner

I've implemeted spinner like [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html) . And now I want to place spinner in ActionBar (setting spinner as CustomView to actionBar) but it doesn't appear there :(

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.planets_spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); 

        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        actionBar.setCustomView(spinner);
```

and here is .XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/parkfragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/planets_spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Please, don't suggest to use ActionBar DropDown List, I can't use it because I'm already using ActionBar Tabs. android doesn't allow to use them both at the same time.
Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is missing this line:

```
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```

See [`ActionBar#setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(boolean showCustom)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(boolean)) for reference.

---

#### Update:

Why is there an empty `FrameLayout` in your layout that occupies all the width and height? Remove it. And remove the `LinearLayout`, too. Just use this as the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Spinner xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/planets_spinner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

And then write something like this and everything is fine:

```
actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.your_layout_with_the_spinner);
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.planets_spinner);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
        R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: after adding this line of code, app crahes with this error 
`You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.`

Comment: Thank you a lot! :) It helped me :)
I have one more question, how to stick spinner to the right side of ActionBar? 
I've tries to use `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` but that didn't work.

Comment: That's only possible using a custom **action** view. But that's a different approach. Read more [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionView).