# Replace the action bar's title with a spinner (drop down)

Tags: android-actionbar, alignment, android, android-actionbar-compat

I am trying to display a spinner in the same position where the action bar's default title appear.
I followed the instruction of the similar [SO case here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11983120/remove-the-title-text-from-the-action-bar-in-one-single-activity?lq=1) ,
so I managed to eliminate the title but still the spinner's position is not aligned to the left, as you can see from this screen-shot

[image: apinner not aligned to the left]

Here are the main definitions of my application to reproduce this case:
**AndroidMenifest.xml:**

```
<application
        android:label="app"            
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" > 
...
    <activity
        android:name="gm.activities.ViewAllActivity">            
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="gm.activities.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
```

**menu_view_all.xml:**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="gm.activities.ViewAllActivity">
    <item android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:title="will be replaced anyway"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.Spinner"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:gravity="left"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

**and the relevant activity:**

```
public class ViewAllActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.view_all_activity);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
...
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_view_all, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.spinner);
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
        spinner.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
        SpinnerAdapter adapter;
        spinner.setAdapter(ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.all_table_views, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item));
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this); // set the listener, to perform actions based on item selection
        return true;
     }
```

So - Can I align the spinner to the left of the action bar and how?
Is it correct to use spinner inside the actionbar and to set it through the *menu.xml* file as I did?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Action `View`s in the menu are always going to align to the right. If you want your `Spinner` to align left, it would be better to set it as a custom `View` on the `ActionBar` using the `setCustomView()` method. A custom `View` will align to the left by default, and will take the place of the title if that is hidden. Please note that this requires that you call `setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true)` on the `ActionBar`.

Comment: I also wanted to mention that calling `setGravity()` on a `View` affects the `View`'s contents, not its layout position. Just FYI.

Comment: Thanks! this is the solution that I implemented, based on your suggestion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15542059/spinner-in-actionbar-doesnt-appear

Comment: @GyRo Cool! Glad to hear you got it working. I just wanted to also mention that that method will still work if you should decide in the future to use a `Toolbar` as your support `ActionBar`. Just make sure to call `setSupportActionBar()` with it. Cheers!

Comment: Hi, I challenge you to answer my following question and be rewarded accordingly, thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29125266/application-header-template

Comment: @GyRo, where is the implemented solution? I did not find it in the linked post